# How to highlight second part of a search string with a colon?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Today I have to ask some of the problems I could not solve by trial and error:

In **vim** I need to highlight just the second word after a search string divided by a colon:

`partA:partB`

Just **"partB" should be highlighted** and the whole expression should be searched. I use `!\zs\w\+\ze` in my system and therefore I experimented with these additional limiters. At the moment I tried

`\(solved:)(Yes\|No\|Almost\)\>`

but I only want Yes, No or Almost highlighted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of combinations I found the solution in my case for myself:

`'solved:\zs\w*'`

Why this works and not Kents fast answer I don't know. But this is the line I now use.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need do those grouping, this should do what you wanted:

```
/solved:\zs\w\+
```

see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work. Just `solved:Yes` works, therefore it's just the expression.

Comment: @TravelTrader it works. check the screenshot in answer

Comment: Thank you. I added (like several other lines): `syntax match  TodoSolve   '/solved:\zs\w\+'` and `highlight  default  link  TodoSolve    Special`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @TravelTrader I tried your two lines, the slash before `solved:...` should be removed. and it worked here.